# libgcrypt.so.11 installed but needed by strongswan

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm, strongswan, l2tp

I'm trying to get StrongSwan package in Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa).

But it shows an issue, even with `libgcrypt-1.8.5-6.el8.x86_64` installed.

[image]

I tried to install StrongSwan and Libgcrypt rpm packages from pkgs.org with `rpm -Uvh package.rpm` but those are requiring another packages already installed.

A few weeks ago I installed same StrongSwan version, but the little difference than previous one... Was the Red Hat subversion: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4 (Ootpa)`

I've checked also the repolist with yum repolist command and both Linux have the same repolist.

I'm little disoriented on this, so that's why I inquiring your support.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install strongswan package for the wrong version of RHEL. You need a package for RHEL 8, but are trying to install the RHEL 7 version. The "el7" in the package version is the indicator that it's wrong.

Comment: @jordanm Thank you. Would you like post your answer? To select it as correct one.